# How to run codes written with maven build in Gradle

Tags: gradle

if I have created a spring Boot application using maven. Now I have to run the same codes in Gradle,So what all changes I have to make.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  [migration guide maven to gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html)

A simple project can migrated by following chapter 3

**3. Run an automatic conversion**

- install gradle to you system
- run gradle init

Accordig to the same guide:

```
You’ll find that the new Gradle build includes the following:

All the custom repositories that are specified in the POM

Your external and inter-project dependencies

The appropriate plugins to build the project (limited to one or more of the Maven Publish, Java and War Plugins)
```